# Why is my message sent only once in Java socket server?

Tags: java, sockets

there is a server that is considered to server multiple clients at the same time.

So when clients connects, he is added to clients array. And when server gets the message, it is sent to all the clients.
It works perfectly when one client is connected, but when I have 2 clients at the same time, the message is sent only once, it doesn't work anymore after that. What's the problem?

**Server**

```
static DataInputStream inputStream;
static DataOutputStream outputStream;

static ServerSocket serverSocket;
static final int PORT = 3003;

static Socket someClient;

static List<Socket> clients = new ArrayList<>();

public Server()
{
    start();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    try{
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);

        print("Server started on " + serverSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());

        while (true)
        {
            someClient = serverSocket.accept();

            new Server();
        }

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    try{
        clients.add(someClient);

        print("Connected from " + someClient.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());

        InputStream sin = someClient.getInputStream();
        OutputStream sout = someClient.getOutputStream();

        inputStream = new DataInputStream(sin);
        outputStream = new DataOutputStream(sout);

        String message;

        while (true)
        {
            message = inputStream.readUTF();

            print(message);

            for (int i = 0; i < clients.size(); i++)
            {
                Socket client = clients.get(i);

                OutputStream os = client.getOutputStream();

                DataOutputStream oss = new DataOutputStream(os);

                oss.writeUTF(message);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
socket = new Socket("0.0.0.0", 3003);

        InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();

        inputStream = new DataInputStream(sin);
        outputStream = new DataOutputStream(sout);

        sendButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(key != null && key.length() == 16)
                {
                    Date date = new Date();

                    String msg = ">> " + nickname + ": " + messageField.getText()+" | " + date.getHours()+":"+date.getMinutes()+"\n";

                    try {
                        outputStream.writeUTF(Encrypt.AESEncrypt(key, msg));
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    messageField.setText("");
                }
                else if(key == null)
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(J_Frame, "Your key field is empty");
                else if(key.length() != 16)
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(J_Frame, "Key's length should be 16 symbols");
            }
        });

        while (true)
        {

            String message;

            message = inputStream.readUTF();

            append("\n" + Encrypt.AESDecrypt(key, message));
        }

    } catch (Exception e1) {
        clear();
        append(">> Unable to connect to the server.");
        hideButtons();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time a client connects to your server, it replaces the previous connection:

```
while (true)
{
        someClient = serverSocket.accept();
        ...
}
```

`someClient` is static:

```
static Socket someClient;
```

which means it is shared by all threads.
Also, access to it is not synchronized in any way, which means changes to its value are not guaranteed to be visible to other threads.

As [Peter Lawrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57695/peter-lawrey) pointed out in the comments, the streams also need to be non-static:

```
static DataInputStream inputStream;
static DataOutputStream outputStream;
```

actually, the fact that you are always reading from the "latest" `inputStream` may be the main cause of the behavior you are describing.
`outputStream` seems to be unused, so it might be best to remove it.

In addition to that, `OutputStreams` may need to be flushed in order to actually send data.

Comment: For static variable only one memory location is allocated irrespective to no of object created. static variables in the class, you are basically into the subject of "singletons" which is where there is intended to be only one instance of a particular class.

Comment: The streams also need to be non static as well.